# BadRequest. Http request failed as there is an error: 'Cannot write more bytes to the buffer than the configured maximum buffer size: 104857600.'

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

My logic app trigger is recurrence under Recurrence get file content will be there on that get file content wil get these error [image]

Comment: How big is your file?

Answer (score 1):

- The error message "BadRequest. Http request failed as there is an error: 'Cannot write more bytes to the buffer than the configured maximum buffer size" **typically occurs when trying to read or write large files in Logic Apps**.
- As mentioned in MS [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-limits-and-config?tabs=consumption,azure-portal) **Trigger or actions in logic Apps Maximum input or output size104,857,600 bytes  (105 MB)**.
- As per documentation to resolve this enable **Allow
  [Chunking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/edit-app-settings-host-settings?tabs=azure-portal#chunking)**
  option in settings of **supported trigger and actions** is the
  possible way as shown in below images.

[image]
[image]

As per @ MayankBargali-MSFTMS Q&A [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/468707/logicapp-sharepoint-badrequest-http-request-failed) **currently SharePoint connector doesn't support message chunking**.

- As an alternative, you can divide the file into smaller chunks, then use a loop or other Logic App operations to process each chunk separately.
- Thanks to @ [Debbies](https://debbiesmspowerbiazureblog.home.blog/2022/03/28/azure-logic-app-copying-a-file-from-sharepoint-to-a-data-lake/) blog .You can refer this blog the same issue is raised and resolved as i said earlier by splitting or removing unnecessary large data.